# JavaScript: Convert "10/30/2015 2:43pm" to a Date object

Tags: javascript, date

As the title suggests, I need to know how to turn strings in the format of "10/30/2015 2:43pm" into JavaScript Date objects. The string comes from Datepair (http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/) and I need to insert it into Mongo DB as a date. I've got Moment.js too if that's useful in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've done any research? People have been writing about how to do this, on the internet, for _decades_. Surely you could have found something?

Comment: Did you look at the Date object constructor? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
new Date("10/30/2015 2:43pm".replace(/([ap]m)$/, " $1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using moment, just provide the format as second parameter:

```
moment("10/30/2015 2:43pm", "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mma");
```

Comment: You forgot about `pm`